# Problem with Magento check file

Tags: magento-1.9

When I run the Magento check file (http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-know-if-my-server-is-compatible-with-magento)

On a new Amazon server install it returns the following:

```
You need PHP 5.2.0 (or greater)'; } else { $pass .='
You have PHP 5.2.0 (or greater)
'; } if(!ini_get('safe_mode')) { $pass .='
Safe Mode is off
'; preg_match('/[0-9]\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/', shell_exec('mysql -V'), $version); if(version_compare($version[0], '4.1.20', '<')) { $fail .= '
You need MySQL 4.1.20 (or greater)
'; } else { $pass .='
You have MySQL 4.1.20 (or greater)
'; } } else { $fail .= '
Safe Mode is on
'; } foreach($extensions as $extension) { if(!extension_loaded($extension)) { $fail .= '
You are missing the '.$extension.' extension
'; } else{  $pass .= '
You have the '.$extension.' extension
'; } } if($fail) { echo '
Your server does not meet the following requirements in order to install Magento.'; echo '
The following requirements failed, please contact your hosting provider in order to receive assistance with meeting the system requirements for Magento:'; echo '

'.$fail.'
'; echo 'The following requirements were successfully met:'; echo '
'.$pass.'
'; } else { echo '
Congratulations! Your server meets the requirements for Magento.

'; echo '
'.$pass.'
'; } } ?>
```

Magento runs fine and I have no problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed the opening tag on the file from

`<?` to `<?php`

Once I added that it works.

Silly me

EDIT:

This also worked

```
; Default Value: On
; Development Value: Off
; Production Value: Off
; http://php.net/short-open-tag
short_open_tag = On
```

Comment: See the [short_open_tag](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) configuration setting.